# Update environment object on listRow click before navigation

Tags: swiftui

Here I have created a observable object, which I added in environment object. On list row click I need to update some values of my environment object before navigating on DetailView. Simply I want to show detail of object based on row selection.

Here is the code I tried:

```
class MyModel:ObservableObject 
{
    var selectDate: String
    var duration: String
    var selectProject: String

    init(dateStr: String, durationStr: String, projectName: String) {
        self.selectDate = dateStr
        self.duration = durationStr
        self.selectProject = projectName
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: MyModel
    @Environment (\.colorScheme) var colorScheme:ColorScheme
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = TimesheetViewModel()
    var body: some View {
      List {                                      
          ForEach(self.viewModel.tasksArr, id:\.id) { taskObj in
               NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) { >need to update **model** before navigating Detail View
                 TimeSheetRowView(taskObj:rowElement)
           }
   }
}
```

Is there any other way to perform same task? Help me out in this

Answer (score 1):

If you have to support **iOS 13-14** you can use `.onAppear` attached to the `destination`.

If you have to support **iOS 15** you can use `.task` attached to the `destination`.

```
struct Store{
    var items: [Task] = [.init(name: UUID().uuidString), .init(name: UUID().uuidString), .init(name: UUID().uuidString)]
    var selected: Task?
    struct Task: Identifiable{
        let id: UUID = .init()
        let name: String
    }
}

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct OnSelectView: View {
    @Environment (\.colorScheme) var colorScheme:ColorScheme
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State var store: Store = .init()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List {
                ForEach(store.items, id:\.id) { taskObj in
                    NavigationLink(destination:
                        detailView(taskObj)
                        //.onAppear{ //or
                        .task {
                            //do something here
                            store.selected = taskObj
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text(taskObj.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func detailView (_ task: Store.Task) -> some View{
        VStack{
            Text(task.name)
            if let selected = store.selected{
                Text(selected.name)
            }else{
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The options above are not technically perform before navigation they are performed as the view "appears".

If you have to support **iOS 16** you should use `NavigationStack` along with `NavigationPath` and `navigationDestination`.

```
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct OnSelectView: View {
    @Environment (\.colorScheme) var colorScheme:ColorScheme
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State var store: Store = .init()
    @State var path: NavigationPath = .init()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path){
            List {
                ForEach(store.items, id:\.id) { taskObj in
                    Button {
                        //Do something
                        store.selected = taskObj
                        
                        path.append(taskObj)
                    } label: {
                        HStack{
                            Text(taskObj.name)
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.forward")
                                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.placeholderText))
                        }
                    }.buttonStyle(.plain)
                }
            }.navigationDestination(for: Store.Task.self) { task in
                detailView(task)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func detailView (_ task: Store.Task) -> some View{
        VStack{
            Text(task.name)
            if let selected = store.selected{
                Text(selected.name)
            }else{
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The iOS 16 solution seems SO CLOSE! The area that the `Spacer()` occupies does not seem tappable. Only the elements on either side of it trigger the button. Ideas?

Comment: Ah, it looks like modifying the HStack with `.contentShape(Rectangle())` fixes that. I think this is sufficient!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Button` and an empty `NavigationLink`. When your button is tapped you programmatically select a `NavigationLink` but before you can perform some actions:

```
@State private var selectedItem: String?

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(self.viewModel.tasksArr, id:\.id) { taskObj in
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        // here you can update your model etc.
                        self.selectedItem = item
                    }, label: {
                        TimeSheetRowView(taskObj:rowElement)
                    })
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), tag: item, selection: self.$selectedItem) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```