# How to inject shared StateObjects into subviews?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view hierarchy of A->B->C

B and C needs to share a StateObject so that both views can be updated when a state change

Code like this

```
struct A : View {
   @StateObject var viewModel : ViewModel()

   var body: some View {
   ...
   .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { route in
                switch route {
                case .libDetail:
                    B(vm: viewModel)
                case .libColoring:
                    C(vm: viewModel)
                }
            }
}
```

And then

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter: Int?
}
```

So now when B changes the counter C will update and vice versa.

However the problem becomes when A needs to get a starting value

```
.navigationDestination(for: String.self) { route in
                    let _ = viewModel.setStartValue(1)  //attempt to set internal counter   
                    switch route {
                    case .libDetail:
                        B(vm: viewModel)
                    case .libColoring:
                        C(vm: viewModel)
                    }
                }
```

will not work, SwiftUI will give error at run time

> [SwiftUI] Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed,
> this will cause undefined behavior.

What is the right software design to do this?

**I would like A to set a start value before pushing the view B onto the navigation stack. Thereafter B can push C onto the stack and B and C should share a StateObject so they can be in sync for updates and they are both free to change the counter's value. But if the stack is pop all the way back to A, the counter should be set to the initial value again**

Comment: have a look at this info, it gives some good examples of how to manage your data in different views: [manage data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine not helpful in this scenario

Comment: Initialize your view-model counter inside the `.onAppear()` modifier of view A.

Comment: The view hierarchy you mention at the start doesn’t match the code so this is a bit confusing (the `switch` statement)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it does match, that's how the navigationDestination API works. It routes each node of the tree

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update environment object on listRow click before navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374453/update-environment-object-on-listrow-click-before-navigation)