# selecting core data entity from ForEach - error cannot conform to view

Tags: swiftui, core-data

From Contentview I click on a button and call ContactListView to display coredata entities in a foreach loop. When a row is selected from ContactListView, I want to save it and pass it back to the contentView. I am trying to accomplish this with @Binding property wrapper in ContentView and a @State property wrapper in ContactListView

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
 @Binding var contact: Contact
 var body: some View {
   NavigationStack {
       VStack (alignment: .leading) {
           Section(header: Text("Contact")){
               ContactListView()
               Spacer()
                   .frame(height:44)
           }
           Section(header: Text("Location")){
               LocationLabelView()
               Spacer()
                   .frame(height:44)
           }
           
       }
   }.navigationTitle(selection.title)
 }
}
```

ContactListView

```
 struct ContactListView: View {
 @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
 @Binding var selectedContact:Contact
 var body: some View {
     NavigationView {
         List {
             ForEach(contacts) { contact in
                 NavigationLink {
                     DisplayContactView(contact: contact)
                    selectedContact = contact
                 } label: {
                     HStack {
                         Text(contact.firstName! + " " + contact.lastName!)
                     }
                 }
             }
             .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
         }
         .navigationTitle("Contacts")
     }
     .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
 }
}
```

on the line  selectedContact = contact, I get error: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'
How to pass the value of core data entity to contentView?

I used TapGesture like this on HStack:

```
var defaults = UserDefaults.standard
.onTapGesture { defaults.setValue(contact.firstName, forKey: "contactName")
}
```

It captures the name , but when I get back to ContentView it wont reload, so it won't execute this piece of code.

```
if let contactId = defaults.string(forKey: "contactName"){ 
    ForEach(contacts) { contact in 
      if let contact = contact {Text(contact.firstName!)
     }
   }
}
```

Is there a way to reload ContentView when it comes into focus?
Is there is better way to pass and retrieve the values?

Comment: You can’t have that kind of swift code inside a view, besides that the code doesn’t make sense. You could perhaps use `selection:` in the `List` init but I am unsure what you want to achieve

Comment: The parent view (ContentView in your case) uses a `@State private var`, while the child view uses a `@Binding var` - that’s how you bind them in SwiftUI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update environment object on listRow click before navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374453/update-environment-object-on-listrow-click-before-navigation)

Comment: @Joakim, When user selects a contact row in ContactListView, I want to store the selected contact object name by assigning it to a global variable and when I come back to ContentView, I would like to and display the contents of that variable. That variable may be a simple String or a struct

Comment: Look up `tapGesture`

Comment: @Joakim, I used your suggestion TapGesture, but I cannot retrieve the value since the ContentView won't reload to execute code. Edited original question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

summing up all relevant and correct comments above, and to give you some starting point here is a working demo:

```
// Demo struct and data
struct Contact: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

let contacts = [
    Contact(name: "Tom"),
    Contact(name: "Eva"),
    Contact(name: "Mike"),
    Contact(name: "Vera"),
    Contact(name: "Chris"),
    Contact(name: "Amy"),
    Contact(name: "Iggy"),
    Contact(name: "Suzy")
]


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var contact: Contact? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                
                Section("Contact") {
                    ContactListView(selectedContact: $contact) // pass selection here!
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height:44)
                }
                
                Section("Selected Contact") {
                    Text(contact?.name ?? "none")
                        .font(.title)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationTitle("Title")
        }
    }
}


struct ContactListView: View {
    
    @Binding var selectedContact: Contact?
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(contacts) { contact in
                Text(contact.name)
                // set selection here on tap
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedContact = contact
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This piece of code worked