# How to do programmatic navigation in swiftui using navigationstack once state changes?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

```swift
struct LoginView: View {

    @State var isUserLoggedIn = false
    
    NavigationStack{
          //.....
          Button {
              Task{
                  await viewModel.doLogin(email: email, password: password)
              }
          } label: {
              Text(Constants.LOGIN)
                .foregroundColor(Constants.BACKGROUND_COLOR)
                .font(Font.custom(Constants.FREDOKA_MEDIUM, size: 25))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
          }
    }.onChange(of: isUserLoggedIn) { isUserLoggedIn in
        debugPrint(newPasswordValue)
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand how to write `NavigationLink` if a state changes, there is no push method in navigation stack as well

Comment: You'r sure, you want a navigation for a NavigationStack or a NavigationSplitView and not a _sheet_ for example? Also, the `doLogin()` what's it doing anyway? It seems odd when you are calling this from your view code. It should be rather somewhere in your application network code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update environment object on listRow click before navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374453/update-environment-object-on-listrow-click-before-navigation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...to do programmatic navigation in swiftui using navigationstack once state changes...`,
try this approach using `NavigationPath` and `navigationDestination`

```
struct LoginView: View {
    
    @State var isUserLoggedIn = false
    @State var path = NavigationPath()   // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {   // <-- here
            Button {
                Task {
                    await viewModel.doLogin(email: email, password: password)
                    if isUserLoggedIn {
                        path.append(1)  // <-- here
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Login")
                    .foregroundColor(Constants.BACKGROUND_COLOR)
                    .font(Font.custom(Constants.FREDOKA_MEDIUM, size: 25))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { _ in     // <-- here
                NextView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NextView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("NextView")
    }
}
```

Comment: wait few hours and i will give u the bounty as well

Answer (score 0):

To add on to workingdog's answer, navigationDestination's Type can only be used for one path. If you try to start a new navigationDestination route using Int, you may end up going back to an empty view or get errors.

Also if you ever need to access the router from different views, you could create an observableObject Router class:

```
final class Router: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path: NavigationPath = .init() 
}
```