# Navigation Link Doesn't works correctly

Tags: swiftui

I just started to learn SwiftUI and I would like to understand why my NavigationLink is not working on this short code. I would like in fact send on firebase all data which works very well and then redirect my user to the main view named UserDashboard has you can see below:

```
NavigationLink(
    destination: UserDashboard().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true),
    label: {
        Button {
            let prospect = ProspectModel()
            Task {
                try await prospect.enregistrementProspect(service: service, categorie: categorie, nom: nom, email: email, tel: tel, adress: adress, siret: siret)
            }
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text("Enregistrer").fontWeight(.semibold)
                Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
            }.foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 48)
        }
    }
).background(Color(.systemBlue))
    .cornerRadius(10)
    .padding(.top, 24)
```

I got to navigation link which goes to the same view I don't think that it's disturb Swift but I would like to mention that. This is my complete code to be clear:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct UserProspect: View {
    @State private var service = ""
    @State private var categorie = ""
    @State private var nom = ""
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var tel = ""
    @State private var adress = ""
    @State private var siret = ""
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View{
        content
    }
    
    var content: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [.blue, .teal], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                    .frame(height: 140).offset(y:-60)
                    .overlay(
                        Text("Recommandation")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 38, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                            .padding(.top, -50)
                    )
                    .padding(.bottom, 0)
                
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                        SelectorView(title: "Type Service", service: $service, pro: "Professionnel", part: "Particulier")
                        
                        SelectorView(title: "Type de categorie", service: $categorie, pro: "Déménagement", part: "Transport")
                        
                        InputView(text: $nom, title: "Nom", placeholder: "Nom à contacter")
                        
                        InputView(text: $email, title: "Email", placeholder: "Email à contacter")
                        
                        InputView(text: $tel, title: "Téléphone", placeholder: "Téléphone à contacter")
                        
                        InputView(text: $adress, title: "Adresse", placeholder: "Adresse complète")
                        
                        if service == "Professionnel" {
                            InputView(text: $siret, title: "Siret", placeholder: "Siret de l'entreprise")
                        }

                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: UserDashboard().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true),
                            label: {
                                Button {
                                    let prospect = ProspectModel()
                                    Task {
                                        try await prospect.enregistrementProspect(service: service, categorie: categorie, nom: nom, email: email, tel: tel, adress: adress, siret: siret)
                                    }
                                } label: {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Enregistrer").fontWeight(.semibold)
                                        Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 48)
                                }
                            }
                        ).background(Color(.systemBlue))
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .padding(.top, 24)
                            

                        NavigationLink {
                            ContentView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                        } label: {
                            Text("Je n'ai finalement pas d'enregistrement")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .font(.system(size: 14))
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }
            .background(Color.white.ignoresSafeArea())
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}


struct UserProspect_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View{
        UserProspect()
    }
}
```

This page is used to register some data.

Refactor many times my code

Comment: A NavigationLink is a type of Button. Having a button inside of a button doesn’t work. You can have the plan button “append” to a “path” for the NavigationStack. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374453/update-environment-object-on-listrow-click-before-navigation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update environment object on listRow click before navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374453/update-environment-object-on-listrow-click-before-navigation)

Comment: this my new code but doesn't work this what you mean ? : `NavigationLink{
UserDashboard()
 }label: {
            HStack{
                    Text("Enregistrement")
                     Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
             }
       }.onSubmit {
                let prospect = ProspectModel()
                            Task {
                                // my request 
                            }
                        }`

Comment: That isn’t in any of the examples in the code in the links

Comment: I don't understand the code you mention I'm new and I just want easy button with my sending firebase data. This should not be so difficult . It's really easy in Kotlin in Symphony and many other language that I know but here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code resolve the issue :

```html
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct UserProspect: View {
    @State private var service = ""
    @State private var categorie = ""
    @State private var nom = ""
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var tel = ""
    @State private var adress = ""
    @State private var siret = ""
    @State private var databaseUpdated = false
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View{
        content
    }
    
    var content: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [.blue, .teal], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                    .frame(height: 140).offset(y:-60)
                    .overlay(
                        Text("Recommandation")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 38, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                            .padding(.top, -50)
                    )
                    .padding(.bottom, 0)
                
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                        SelectorView(title: "Type Service", service: $service, pro: "Professionnel", part: "Particulier")
                        
                        SelectorView(title: "Type de categorie", service: $categorie, pro: "Déménagement", part: "Transport")
                        
                        InputView(text: $nom, title: "Nom", placeholder: "Nom à contacter")
                        
                        InputView(text: $email, title: "Email", placeholder: "Email à contacter")
                        
                        InputView(text: $tel, title: "Téléphone", placeholder: "Téléphone à contacter")
                        
                        InputView(text: $adress, title: "Adresse", placeholder: "Adresse complète")
                        
                        if service == "Professionnel" {
                            InputView(text: $siret, title: "Siret", placeholder: "Siret de l'entreprise")
                        }

                        Button(action: {
                            let prospect = ProspectModel()
                            Task {
                                try await prospect.enregistrementProspect(service: service, categorie: categorie, nom: nom, email: email, tel: tel, adress: adress, siret: siret)
                                
                            }
                            databaseUpdated = true}) {
                                
                                Text("Envoyer ma recommandation").padding()
                                    .background(Color.blue)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32, height: 48)
                                    
                                    
                            }
                        NavigationLink(destination: UserDashboard().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true), isActive: $databaseUpdated, label:{EmptyView()})
                            NavigationLink {
                                UserDashboard().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                            } label: {
                            Text("Je n'ai finalement pas d'enregistrement")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .font(.system(size: 14))
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                            }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }
            .background(Color.white.ignoresSafeArea())
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}


struct UserProspect_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View{
        UserProspect()
    }
}
```