# in this simple SwiftUI form, I get the error that my use of navigationview has been deprecated in iOS 16. I've tried variations of the new format

Tags: swift, swiftui, deprecated

Here is my form {} structure

```
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Settings")) {
                Toggle(isOn: $allowEmailNotifications) {
                    Text("Ok to Email Tee Times, etc.")
                        .font(stateManager.myNormalHNFont)
                }
                .padding()
                .onChange(of: allowEmailNotifications) { newValue in
                    me.okToSendEmail = newValue
                }
            }

            Section(header: Text("Utilities")) {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: PlayerMigrationView(),
                    tag: "ClaimMyRounds",
                    selection: $selection
                ) {
                    Button {
                        self.selection = "ClaimMyRounds"
                    } label: {
                        Text("Consolidate My Rounds To This Account")
                            .font(stateManager.myNormalHNFont)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                }
            }
        }
```

I've read the documentation and have been trying to get the new format to work but to no avail.  When I try this format, I get an error on the Form { line that says I am passing a closure to a view that does not take one...

```
Form {
    Section(header: Text("Settings")) {
        Toggle(isOn: $allowEmailNotifications) {
            Text("Ok to Email Tee Times, etc.")
                .font(stateManager.myNormalHNFont)
        }
        .padding()
        .onChange(of: allowEmailNotifications) { newValue in
            me.okToSendEmail = newValue
        }
    }

    Section(header: Text("Utilities")) {
        Button {
            self.selection = "ClaimMyRounds"
        } label: {
            Text("Consolidate My Rounds To This Account")
                .font(stateManager.myNormalHNFont)
        }
        .padding()
        .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
        .background (
            NavigationLink(value: "ClaimMyRounds", selection: $selection) { EmptyView() }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { _ in PlayerMigrationView() }
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: How are you using NavigationView?  It's not in the sample code...

Comment: Oddly enough, I don't have it in the view at all.  So, without it, the deprecated version works fine but I get that deprecation warning in Xcode.  When I use NavigationView {} to wrap the whole Form, It still fine works with the deprecated version - but i still see the deprecation warning.   But the newer NavigationLink {} version gets the same "closure" error and won't compile, regardless of whether i have a navigationview{} wrapping it.

Comment: You shouldn't use `NavigationView` anymore use `NavigationStack` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

Comment: When I encase the form inside either one, i get the same enclosure error.  When I comment out the "Form{"   and its closing "}" the error shifts to the $selection parameter on the navigationlink.  it says it is expecting a Binding Bool not Binding String.  So I switch out selection to be a Bool and I .toggle() it on click.   Still no joy.  At that point it goes back to the deprecation error, "'init(_:isActive:destination:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: use NavigationLink(value:label:), or navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:), inside a NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView"

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationdestination(ispresented:destination:)

Comment: The above link has the alternative for the “isActive” version. Also don’t use the EmptyView hack there are far better ways of handing this.

Comment: This link will give you some insights https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374453/update-environment-object-on-listrow-click-before-navigation/75195864#75195864

Answer (score 0):

The deprecation warning may be being caused by the `NavigationLink` initializer that you are trying to use. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(destination:tag:selection:label:)) for `init(destination:tag:selection:label:)` suggests using `init(value:label:)` as alternative.

You can also simplify the way you are using the `NavigationLink`, because a link behaves like a button. So there is no need to wrap the button with a link, or a link with a button. Just use a `NavigationLink` without involving a `Button` at all.

Then as *lorem ipsum* commented, you need to use a `NavigationStack` and not a `NavigationView`.

So try changing it to something like this:

```swift
NavigationStack {
    Form {
        Section(header: Text("Settings")) {
            Toggle(isOn: $allowEmailNotifications) {
                Text("Ok to Email Tee Times, etc.")
                    .font(stateManager.myNormalHNFont)
            }
            .padding()
            .onChange(of: allowEmailNotifications) { newValue in
                me.okToSendEmail = newValue
            }
        }

        Section(header: Text("Utilities")) {
            NavigationLink(value: "ClaimMyRounds") {
                Text("Consolidate My Rounds To This Account")
                    .font(stateManager.myNormalHNFont)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { selection in
        PlayerMigrationView()
    }
}
```

If you are compiling against iOS 17 then you will also find that your `onChange` callback is deprecated too. If you want to fix it then just change it to:

```swift
.onChange(of: allowEmailNotifications) { oldValue, newValue in
```