# SwiftUI NavigationStack present Alert

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a List in NavigationStack:

```
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
        List(viewModel.items, id: \.id) { item in
                HStack {
                    ItemView(item: item)
                    NavigationLink(value: item) { EmptyView() }
                        .opacity(0.0)
                }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .navigationDestination(for: SettingItem.self) { item in
                DetailsView()
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
```

By tapping on one item I need to show Alert view with confirmation buttons YES, NO.
I tried

```
.navigationDestination(for: SettingItem.self) { item in
                if item.check == true {
                  AlertView()
                } else {
                  DetailsView()
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                }
```

NavigationStack push new view on stack, but I need stay on the same view, just show confirmation alert.

Comment: Does this help: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-an-alert ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374453/update-environment-object-on-listrow-click-before-navigation/75195864#75195864