Await in NavigationLink Swift?
I am currently making an app (as a first time IOS developer) and I have 2 textboxes and a button on a page. One of the text boxes asks the user for a game code. What I am trying to do is when the user presses the button, it grabs the "Game Name" from the database and uses that as the destination for the NavigationLink. The only issue I am running into currently is, The navigation doesn't want to wait for the function to fully finish.
There are 2 main functions that it is using (other than the db call which DOES get the name when the gameRoom code is entered), the first one I have it just getting the game name and making it a string.
    func roomGameName() -> String {

        var gameName: String = ""

        getGameRoomName(roomCode: gameCode) { roomName in
            if let name = roomName {
                gameName = name
            } else {
                print("Room name not found.")
            }
        }
        return gameName
    }

The next function is used to get the actual view that is supposed to be showed from the string gameName
func destinationView(for item: String, gameCode: String, name: String) -> AnyView {
    switch item {
    case "Wizard":
        AnyView(WizardView(code: gameCode, name: name))
    case "Farkle":
        AnyView(FarkleView())
    case "Quixx":
        AnyView(QuixxView())
    case "Yahtzee":
        AnyView(YahtzeeView())
    default:
        AnyView(Text("No Game Selected"))
    }
}

and this NavigationLink is in my view with the button and 2 textboxes
NavigationLink(
    destination: destinationView(
                     for: roomGameName(), gameCode: gameCode,
                     name: name)
                 ) {
                     EmptyView()
                   }

Is there a way for NavigationLink to not render the new view until roomGameName() is finished? If I just do WizardView() instead, it works how I expect it too.

In this case I wouldn’t necessarily use a navigation link but a button to do the work and then set some state that’s triggers the navigation. If you have a navigationstack you can use a path array and the async work will append the next data onto it. Not a full answer as I’m on my phone but this should give you a bit to google.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374453/update-environment-object-on-listrow-click-before-navigation/75195864#75195864

What iOS versions are you supporting?

I am using iOS 18.0 with the Xcode-Beta. I'm now just looking into a NavigationStack and it seems like it can fix my issue because of lazy loading. I will keep you updated

    /*The issue you're encountering is due to the asynchronous nature of your getGameRoomName function. Since getGameRoomName uses a closure to return the game name, the roomGameName() function returns an empty string before the closure has a chance to update the gameName variable.
    
    To solve this, you can use a combination of state management and the @State or @StateObject property wrappers in SwiftUI. Here's how you can approach it:*/
    
   @State private var gameName: String = ""
@State private var isNavigationActive: Bool = false

func fetchGameName() {
    getGameRoomName(roomCode: gameCode) { roomName in
        if let name = roomName {
            gameName = name
            isNavigationActive = true
        } else {
            print("Room name not found.")
            isNavigationActive = false
        }
    }
}

    
//This way, the navigation will only trigger once isNavigationActive is set to true.


   NavigationLink(
    destination: destinationView(for: gameName, gameCode: gameCode, name: name),
    isActive: $isNavigationActive,
    label: {
        Text("Go to Game")
    }
)

//This will start the game name retrieval and eventually trigger the navigation.


Button(action: {
    fetchGameName()
}) {
    Text("Fetch Game and Navigate")
}

    //If the gameName is empty, the NavigationLink will display an EmptyView. Once the fetchGameName function completes and updates the gameName, the NavigationLink will navigate to the correct view.


I thought isActive was deprecated
